# Where does "give something a whirl" come from?

Tags: etymology

While

> My head is in a whirl.

makes sense to me ([whirl](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/whirl_2): a movement of something spinning round and round) I wonder about

> *give something a whirl*

which means *to try something to see if you like it or can do it*.

I don't get the connection between *whirl* and *to try*. Where does is it come from?

Comment: I've always associated it with asking someone to dance.  I don't know if that's really legit, but it makes sense to me.  When you give something a whirl, you haven't made a commitment yet, you're just giving it (her or him) a whirl as a test run (but an enjoyable test run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From etymonline for *[whirl](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=whirl)*,

> figurative sense of "confused activity" is recorded from 1550s. Colloquial sense of "tentative attempt" is attested from 1884, Amer.Eng.

It may be that the "confused activity" sense developed into the "tentative attempt" sense; etymonline does not indicate, and apparently doesn't address the question of origin of *give something a whirl*.  But one can see that the sense "make a tentative attempt to do something" is not far from the current meaning (to try doing something one is unfamiliar with or hasn't tried before or is uncertain about).  There is sourceless speculation at [phrases.org.uk](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/44/messages/927.html) that the phrase arose from spinning a roulette wheel, or a "wheel-of-fortune", or a "whirlygig" colonial toy.
Also see entry in [thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+a+whirl), which quotes the Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms as saying of *whirl*,

> to try something; Usage notes: often used in the form *give it a whirl*: We've always wanted to take a cruise in the Caribbean, so we decided to give it a whirl.

Comment: It's like "take it for a spin".

Comment: The wheel of fortune interpretation makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I've always thought it was a reference to how you started the early Ford Model T's  which you had to crank the engine by hand to start them. It was very hard and tiring process particularly in cold weather. Hence the saying "do you want to give it a whirl"

Comment: Interesting theory; do you have any reliable references that back it up?

Answer (score -1):

Prior to the 1930's, and when asking a young lady to dance, a young man would 'give her a whirl', and by chance, her dress would blossom and expose her ankles.
By the 1950's, the term was used more often to describe chance. "I'll give it a whirl' would mean that he/she is will try to attempt a goal.

Comment: Can you add support and links to your answer?